# How to setup Cucumber-JVM-TestNG with Ant (Build.xml)

Tags: ant, cucumber, testng, cucumber-jvm

How can I setup Cucumber-JVM-TestNG with Ant? My framework is designed in JVM-testNG with ANT and I'm trying to use cucumber on same. I have not been able to succeed with this.

Comment: Never mind, I've figured out the solution. Let me know if any one need an idea on this. Thanks!

Comment: If you have solved the issue, you can post an answer to your own question.